# Tensor product - result as column vector or matrix

Tags: tensor-products

I have a bit of quantum computing on my current semester and I am currently reading about tensors. I have read article on outer product (which is described as tensor product of two vectors): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product and this online pdf: http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/tensorproduct.pdf.

I am now a bit confused, in Wikipedia article the result of tensor product on two vectors is described as matrix and in the pdf I linked, tensor of two vectors is column vector (page 6). I can see that those two are very similar (we multiply each basis coordinate from two vectors) but I am interested if both of the notations are correct and what purpose does it serve to have both of them?

Comment: It seems on page 6 one is writing a 2*3 matrix in form of a 6 elements vector, just a different way of presenting things